# Reading massive JSON files into Spark Dataframe

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a large nested NDJ (new line delimited JSON) file that I need to read into a single spark dataframe and save to parquet. In an attempt to render the schema I use this function:

```
def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null) : Array[Column] = {
        schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
          val colName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)
          f.dataType match {
            case st: StructType => flattenSchema(st, colName)
            case _ => Array(col(colName))
          }
        })
  }
```

on the dataframe that is returned by reading by

`val df = sqlCtx.read.json(sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path).values)`

I've also switched this to `val df = spark.read.json(path)` so that this only works with NDJs and not multi-line JSON--same error.

This is causing an out of memory error on the workers
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

I've altered the jvm memory options and spark executor/driver options to no avail

Is there a way to stream the file, flatten the schema, and add to a dataframe incrementally? Some lines of the JSON contain new fields from the preceding entires...so those would need to be filled in later.

Answer (score 2):

No work around. The issue was with the JVM object limit. I ended up using a scala json parser and built the dataframe manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in multiple ways.

First while reading, you can provide the schema for dataframe to read json or you can allow the spark to infer the schema by itself.

Once the json is in dataframe, you can follow the following ways to flatten it.

a. Using explode() on dataframe - to flatten it.
b. Using spark sql and access the nested fields using . operator. You can find examples [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/02/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-spark-sql.html)

Lastly, if you want to add new columns to dataframe
a. First option,using withColumn() is one approach. However this will be done for each new column added and for entire data set.
b. Using sql to generate new dataframe from existing - this may be easiest
c. Lastly, using map, then accessing elements, get old schema, add new values, create new schema and finally get the new df - as below

One withColumn will work on entire rdd. So generally its not a good practise to use the method for every column you want to add. There is a way where you work with columns and their data inside a map function. Since one map function is doing the job here, the code to add new column and its data will be done in parallel.

a. you can gather new values based on the calculations

b. Add these new column values to main rdd as below

```
val newColumns: Seq[Any] = Seq(newcol1,newcol2)
Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq.init ++ newColumns)
```

Here row, is the reference of row in map method

c. Create new schema as below

```
val newColumnsStructType = StructType{Seq(new StructField("newcolName1",IntegerType),new StructField("newColName2", IntegerType))
```

d. Add to the old schema

```
val newSchema = StructType(mainDataFrame.schema.init ++ newColumnsStructType)
```

e. Create new dataframe with new columns

```
val newDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(newRDD, newSchema)
```

Comment: How does it address `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` resulting from `wholeTextFiles`?

Comment: I was addressing "Is there a way to stream the file, flatten the schema, and add to a dataframe incrementally? Some lines of the JSON contain new fields from the preceding entires...so those would need to be filled in later.". I see no question regarding memory issue resolution. So gave him multiple approaches.

Comment: If NDJ is JSONL then OP shouldn't use wholeTextFiles. If it is not this won't help.

Comment: All you can do with textFile() can be done with wholeTextFile() but with bad performance . The reverse is not true - due to multi line scenarios. Since here its a NDJ as mentioned, the best possible alternative is come out of wholetext files and also alternatives as mentioned above. Let me know if I am missing anything

Comment: I was using wholeTextFile to account for multi-line JSON and switched to the normal `val df = spark.read.json(path)` Yet, this still gives me a java OOM. I've tried increasing the memory with -xmx options and I've also increased memory on driver/executor nodes. The json file is ~ 1G and I have 16gigs available to test on my laptop.

Comment: You mentioned OOM error on executors. And also you say that the file is huge. My suggestion would be first try t get the logic working with small data set. Then you can try the same on actual file. Coming back to your above two contradicting statements - if you are having trouble reading the file, then your are getting OOM error at driver it self. ON the other hand, if its on worker node, then reading was good and error occurs due to some logic performed on executors.